# Why definite integral of undefined function returns unevaluated?

Tags: integral, maple

Why can Maple yield the result of `int(q(t)*diff(q(t),t),t)` = `(q(t)^2)/2` (indefinite integral) but with `int(q(t)*diff(q(t),t),t=0..t)` (definite integral) it returns unevaluated?

I expect the result of the definite integral to be `(q(t)^2 - q(0)^2)/2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
int(q(t)*diff(q(t),t),t=0..t,continuous);

                    2           2
           -1/2 q(0)  + 1/2 q(t)
```

Comment: @sonEtLumiere The fundamental theorem of calculus only applies to continuous functions. It's not known a priori whether q is continuous.

Comment: The result you're expecting is not correct in general. The `continuous` option to the `int` command allows you to aver that the integrand is continuous and force the issue.